# How to do react native button by clicking icon alert ('OK')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-icons

how to do react native button by clicking icon alert ('OK'),
i want to place dots-three-vertical
Thanks...

```
export default [
  {
    _id: '1001',
    name: 'Weeks',
    one: 'Monday',
    two: 'Tuesday',
    three: 'Wednesday',
    four: 'Thursday',
    five: 'Friday',
    six: 'Saturday',
    seven: 'Sunday',
  },
```

```
export default (props) => {
  const {object} = props.route.params;
  const {textContainer} = styles;

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {Object.keys(object)
        .filter(
          (item) =>
            item !== '_id' &&
            item !== 'name' &&
        )
        .map((children) => (
          <Text key={children} style={textContainer}>
            {object[children]}
          </Text>
        ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

[look picture here dot-three-vertical icon example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuLQ2.jpg)

Comment: So you have button event handler that creates an alert dialog, and you want to add an icon when the user confirms the dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how to implement the and have it display on the right,
if you're using expo, you can import the correct Icon package from expo vector icons like so:

```
import { SimpleLineIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
```

Then create your scrollview like this:

```html
<ScrollView>
      {Object.keys(object)
        .filter(
          (item) =>
            item !== '_id' &&
            item !== 'name' &&
        )
        .map((children) => (
        <View style={styles.listItem}>
        <Text key={children} style={textContainer}>
            {object[children]}
          </Text>
          
          <SimpleLineIcons name="options-vertical" size={24} color="red" />
        </View>
          
        ))}
    </ScrollView>
    
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    listItem : {
    padding : 10,
    flexDirection : "row",
    justifyContent : "space-between",
    alignItems : "center"
    }
    })
```

You can add an onPress listener on the icons to do whatever you want. If you want to show an alert, use Alert.alert() and configure it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thank you so much;

<ScrollView>
      {Object.keys(object)
        .filter(
          (item) =>
            item !== '_id' &&
            item !== 'name' &&
        )
        .map((children) => (
        <View style={styles.listItem}>
        <Text key={children} style={textContainer}>
            {object[children]}
          </Text>
          
          <SimpleLineIcons name="options-vertical" size={24} color="red" />
        </View>
          
        ))}
    </ScrollView>
    
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    listItem : {
    padding : 10,
    flexDirection : "row",
    justifyContent : "space-between",
    alignItems : "center"
    }
    })
```